# Use Greasemonkey to remove tables

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying remove 2 tables from simple html page. The page contain only 2 tables, Heres the page code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table class="details" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<th>1</th>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<h3>Table 2</h3>

<table class="details" border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<th>1</th>
<td>2</td>
</tr><tr>
<th>3</th> 
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no problem removing one of the tables using:

```
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
```

or

```
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(1);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
```

But I fail to remove both tables using those command in a row on my user script:

```
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(1);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the old table #0, the old table #1 becomes the new table #0. Thus, if you try to get table #1, it'll fail.

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian's answer really is the answer you'll be looking for, but for clarity, I'll show how you could do it:
You could either do

```
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
```

Watch the fact that I'm removing the `.item[0]` both times; it'll remove the first one on the page both times.
Else, this:

```
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(1);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
var elmDeleted = document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0);
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
```

... Which will remove the second, then the first one.

To be (what I call) neat: (==more compact)

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)(temp=document.getElementsByClassName('details').item(0)).parentNode.removeChild(temp);
```

As a side note, since you say that there'll be only 2 tables on the page, you can replace every `document.getElementsByClassName('details')` with `document.getElementsByTagName('table')`.

Also, in my compact version, you can replace the `i<2` with `i<document.getElementsByClassName('details').length` to remove **all** 'detail'-tables instead of just the first two.

Hope this helped :)